# GoogleTag Manager transforming root URL

Tags: iframe, http-status-code-404

A client of ours currently uses an error reporting service which logs a number of errors thrown across the site and alerts us when a certain threshold is hit. This morning we received a large number of errors to do with the GoogleTag Manager service, however I'm unsure how or why these 404's are occurring and was wondering if anyone had seen similar behavior before.

What appears to be happening is that the GoogleTag iframe URL is being appended to the sites root URL and is thus causing a 404.

To illustrate this more clearly, we have the following iframe code

```
<iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KJHJ"
```

and we are seeing the following URL returned as a 404

```
www.website.com//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KJHJ
```

Has anyone had an experience of this happening? Or would be able to indicate or think of any reason why this would have started to occur suddenly?

As a side note, this has been happening repeatedly from various IPs for the last few hours.

Thanks.

Comment: Even I face the same error in my website. Can't find any resources too :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheme-relative urls work fine in all common browsers, so I think that these errors might be caused by some crawlers that do not parse such urls correctly. Have you checked the IP addresses in your logs to see where they come from?

Independent of that - if you need to get rid of these 404 errors then adding the protocol should do the trick. So change the GTM code such that both urls start with the protocol (http:// or https://) and the 404 errors should go away.